# Javascript: assigning new objects with unique random properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

I'm attempting to create an array of objects based on a constructor. During creation of the constructed objects each is assigned an ID & a random integer as the first value of an array.

```
var defaults = {
  x: 0, 
  y: 0, 
  d: [1,1], // destination 


  s: 2 // speed 
};

var stage = document.getElementById('stage');

var oM = function ( vars ) {

    var vars = vars;

    this.fn = {};
    this.v = vars.v;

    this.i = vars.i;
    this.v.d = [ 0, 0 ];

    this.init = function( i ) {

        var r = Math.floor( Math.random() * 999);
        var d = Math.floor( Math.random() * 999);

        var e = document.createElement('div');
        e.id = 'bit-' + i;
        e.classList.add('bit', 'mob', 'test');

        stage.appendChild(e);

        this.v.x = r;
        this.v.d[0] = d;

        console.log( this.v.d );

        this.e = document.getElementById( 'bit-' + i );
        this.e.style.left = this.v.x ;

    };

    this.move = function() {

        var i = this.i;
        var p = this.v.x;  
        var d = this.v.d[0]; 
        var s = this.v.s; 
        var m = 'stay';

        if ( ( p > d && ( p - s ) <= d ) || ( p < d && ( p + s ) >= d ) ) {
            p = d;
        } else if ( p > d ) {
            // move W 
            p = p - s;
            m = 'west';
        } else if ( p < d ) {
            // move E
            p = p + s;
            m = 'east';
        } 

        // console.log('index: ' + i + ' x: ' + p + ': moved: ' + m + ' @' + s + ': toward: ' + d + ' from: ' + this.v.x);
        this.v.x = p;
        this.e.style.left = this.v.x ;
        console.log( this.v.d );

    }
};



var eng = {};

eng.arr = [];

eng.init = function() {

    for ( var i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {

        var u = new oM( { 
            i: i,
            v: defaults
        });


        u.init( i );
        eng.arr.push( u );
        // console.log( t );

    };

}

eng.turn = function() { 

    for ( var i = 0; i < eng.arr.length; i++ ) {

        console.log( eng.arr[ i ].v.d );
      // eng.arr[ i ].move();

    };

};


var f = 0;

eng.init();




console.time('turn: 0');

window.run = function () {

    if (f <= 9.1300) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame( run );

        eng.turn();
        console.timeEnd('turn: ' + f);
        f = f + 1;
        console.time('turn: ' + f);

    };

};

run();
```

In the above you can see two separate namespaces: 
`oM` contains methods for object construction & manipulation. 
`eng` contains methods & context for interacting with all objects.

When the objects are first constructed they each have a unique random number here: `this.v.d[0]` or `eng.arr[#].v.d[0]` (currently output to console).

However once the `for` in `eng.init()` has finished you'll note that all the objects in the array `eng.arr` now have the same (the last added object's) value for `this.v.d[0]`.

How is the final objects value being set to the other array items? The ID key is not being affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is the final objects value being set to the other array items? The ID key is not being affected.

Because `v` (and, consecutively, `v.d`) is **the same hash/object** for all your created objects. You're mutating the same place in memory. [Copy/clone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/125816) the defaults for each object.

The ID isn't repeated because you **reassign** the reference to a new object rather than mutate existing object.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Would using Object.assign() make sense in this context to copy the defaults? It seems to work well & is the simplest solution I saw.

Comment: @MarcusWebb: no, it only does shallow cloning. You need deep cloning (to clone the array too).

Comment: Ah, ok, I was reading about that (deep cloning) earlier. Much appreciated, I will follow up.